# What is wrong with the setup of Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Because I want to install a new clear version of Hyperledger Fabric, I deleted old Hyperledger file of one month ago, and run "vagrant destroy".

I run "vagrant up", and "vagrant ssh" successfully.

I "make peer" successfully, when I run "peer", if failed. 
When I run "make peer" and "peer" again, the error is pop up as below:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ make peer
make: Nothing to be done for `peer'.
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ peer
No command 'peer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
 Command 'peel' from package 'ears' (universe)
 Command 'pear' from package 'php-pear' (main)
peer: command not found
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ cd peer
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$ ls -l
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   204 Jun 26 01:16 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 17342 Jun 25 14:18 core.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 35971 Jun 25 14:18 main.go
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  1137 Jun 23 08:46 main_test.go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary `peer` file's location is ./build/bin/ folder. 
For your configuration the full path is "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin/"

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you one thing I observed when I pulled code from gitHub last week, [*Thursday to be exact*].
Make command had created the executable in "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin/". But one pretty thing which I found was, it had copied the same to "/hyperledger/build/bin". And the $PATH variable now included "/hyperledger/build/bin" also.

So to answer your question, you have two options :-
**1.** one retain your current version of code & Navigate into the **bin folder in the fabric directory** and see whether peer executable is present there. ? If yes, then execute the rest of the code.
**2.** Pull the latest copy from gitHub.com and make peer from fabric directory as usual. But execute peer from anywhere. :)

Comment: "it had copied the same to '/hyperledger/build/bin'". Yes, correct. but I do not have "build" under "hyperledger" folder. I found peer executable file under ./build/bin/ folder, but it really should introduced in wiki.

Comment: same. no /build in /hyperledger/fabric.